# Java - How to repopulate an arraylist with previously known elements

Tags: java

I have an arraylist populated by four elements, the order of which is random (they are put here by random from another arraylist).  I then have a for loop that repeats 10 times, at the end of each repetition I use the clear methods to clear all the elements of the arraylist.  However, when I start a new repetition, I would like to repopulate my arraylist with the old (previously worked with) elements that were members of the list in the previous repetition, so that I can use the elements again.  And I would like to repeat that until I get out of my 10-repetition for loop.  Is there any way to achieve this at all?

Code in addition to my question:

```
 ArrayList<String> answerPegs =  new  ArrayList<String>();
  // add element to ArrayList

    ArrayList<String> mySecretAnswer = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int n = 4; n > 0; n--) 
    {       
         //populate mySecretAnswer with elements from answerPegs
    }


    ArrayList<String> clone1 = mySecretAnswer;

    for (int q = 0; q < 10; q++) { 

        for (o = 0; o < 4; o++)
        {
         }
      // called clear() method here

    } // END OF 10-ROW LOOP
```

Comment: In addition to @beerbajay's comment, why not just remove the clear() call?

Comment: Since I'm programming Mastermind, my approach is to replace colors that have been already compared with an empty string, so that they won't be check again (not a very effective approach, of course).  So at the end, either part of the original arraylist are partially replaced with empty strings and I can't use it again, or I will have to manually clear the list myself.

Comment: Why not save the indicies originally inserted from the source list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest simply having 2 lists - keep a pristine copy of the original list, and then iterate over + clear a copy of that list.

```
public void doRepetitions(List<Object> original)
{
    for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
    {
        List<Object> working = new ArrayList<Object>( original );
        doStuffWithList(working);
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
Since you've posted your code, I can give a more specific answer:

You can change your `clone` to be:

```
ArrayList<String> clone1 = new ArrayList<String>(mySecretAnswer);
```

And then move that to be inside your for loop:

```
for (int q = 0; q < 10; q++)
{ 
    ArrayList<String> clone1 = new ArrayList<String>(mySecretAnswer);
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use 2 loops nested and just have the inner loop be the for loop 10 times then clear once at the end